# Export list as a .csv file, but not seeing the commas

Tags: export, csv-format

My goal is to export a list of numbers into a file, with a comma between each value. Executing the following commands seems to produce a file with a new line between each entry.

```
v = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3};
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[]; 
Export["v.csv", v, "csv"];
```

When I open the file with notepad, what I see is 
1.1
2.2
3.3

What I would like to see is comma separated values, like the following: 
1.1, 2.2, 3.3

Recommendations?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your expression `v` is a vector, it's being interpreted as one line per number.

The following gives your desired result.

```
Export["v.csv", {v}, "csv"]
```